# Apache configuration on OS X Yosemite

Tags: configuration, osx-yosemite, apache2.4

After upgrading to Yosemite, my Apache configuration seems broken. My main problem is that the Document Root is changed. Now all I get is a "It works!" page.

I can't figure out why, everything looks fine to me.

I have set up properly `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and DocumentRoot is in fact `/Library/WebServer/Documents` as it was before... Also `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` contains the same... Moreover, the additional configuration to have a directory for the user (e.g. `localhost/~user1`) is not loaded.

I don't know what to do.

Can somebody help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Future readers may want to start with [installing Apache, PHP, and MySQL on Mac OS X Yosemite](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x/) the *right way*.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Apparently the document root changed to /usr/local/var/apache2/htdocs . 
I found this by checking what config file was being loaded by apache.

```
sudo apachectl -V
```

You should see something like this

```
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/apache24/2.4.10"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/local/Cellar/apache24/2.4.10/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/usr/local/var/run/apache2/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/usr/local/etc/apache2/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/usr/local/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

At the very end shows that is no longer loading the /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf but instead is loading it from /usr/local/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

An easy workaround would be to move all your /Library/Webserver/Documents to the new DocumentRoot location /usr/local/etc/apache2/htdocs

Or just pass the old httpd.conf file to apachectl by doing

```
sudo apachectl -f /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer. I managed to solve my problem: it was actually loaded the proper directory root; the trick was that it was looking only for `index.html` as as default file in a directory. Now, what seems strange to me is the fact that there is no `index.html` file containing `It Works!` in this directory... So I don't know why that was displayed. PS the directory you mentioned doesn't exist for me...

Comment: The "It works!" text comes from /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html.en, the directory of which is specified in (at least my) httpd.conf as DocumentRoot.